# array_count_values randomise matching values

Tags: php

I know the below code

```
<?php
    $array = array("1", "hello", "1", "world", "hello");    
    print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

I would like to retrieve the value which has been repeated the most, or if there are multiple matching instances which have been repeated the most e.g "hello" and "1" randomise them instead of retrieving the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live: http://ideone.com/D1Ydbd

```
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello",'2','2','2','3','3','3');

$s = array_count_values($array);
$mostRepeated = max($s);

$s = array_filter( $s, function($v) use ($mostRepeated) {
  return $v==$mostRepeated;
});

print_r($s);    
echo array_rand($s);  // randomized
```

Step:

- find the highest count
- remove elements with less frequency
- return an element random with `array_rand`

Note that I wrote this function to be transparent whenever there are a single or multiple entries with the same value count.